# gcc linking error for assembly program

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to execute an assembly program which calculates the roots of a quadratic equation.

```
nasm -f elf64 assgn10.asm
gcc -o assgn10 assgn10.o
```

> /usr/bin/ld: assgn10.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>
> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have used 2 macros.

```
%macro myprintf 1
mov rdi,formatpf
sub rsp,8
movsd xmm0,[%1]
mov rax,1
call printf
add rsp,8
syscall
%endmacro

%macro myscanf 1
mov rdi,formatsf
mov rax,0
mov rsi,qword[%1]
call scanf
;syscall
%endmacro
```

This is how my .bss section looks.

```
section .bss

a resq 1
b resq 1
c resq 1
b2 resq 1 ; b square
fac resq 1 ; 4ac
delta resq 1 ; delta value
rdelta resq 1 ; root of delta
r1 resq 1 ;root 1
r2 resq 1 ;root 2
ta resq 1  ; 2a
realn resq 1
img1 resq 1
img2 resq 1
```

The same program worked without fuss on a different PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The same program worked without fuss on a different pc.

Your `gcc` is configured to produce [position-independent executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) by default (`configure --enable-default-pie ...`) and your assembly is not compatible with that.

This should work:

```
gcc -o assgn10 assgn10.o -no-pie
```

Comment: What if I want a position independent executable? Can NASM do that?